# how to change the dimensions of a jpg image in R?

Tags: r, resize, jpeg, image-resizing

I always resized images in CorelDraw from 1219,20 x 914,40mm to 78.36x51.00 to make photo boards. But now it turns out I have a lot of images in different folders and I needed to create an auto-lop to do this for me. If I were to do this in Corel like I used to do, it would take a lot of time.
I have used the the `resize` function from `Magick`  package, but didn't have obtain sucess.

```
resize(Image,  "78.36x51.00!")

Error in resize("78,36x51,00!") : 
Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer].
```

So I also tried the  `image_scale` function, in this case the dimensions changed, but the size and resolution of the image was much smaller than expected.

```
 image_scale(Image, "78.36x51.00!")
```

- Demonstration with the generated image after the resize (photo)  and the expected size (white square)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I never used this package, so I don't know. I would use ImageMagick. One can run it from R with the `system` function.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I tried to instal the package but give me an error : package ‘ImageMagick’ is not available for this version of R

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. ImageMagick is not a R package. Google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation indicates that `magick`'s [scaling](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#Cut_and_edit) functions are based on pixels. Scaling based on X and Y dimensions expressed as pixels is shown below.

I'm not sure if this directly addresses the issue because the units in the question seem to change and dots per inch ([dpi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch)) is not defined. 1219,20 x 914,40 is in mm, but the units for 78.36 x 51.00 are undefined. The first pair of numbers has an aspect ratio of 1.3 while the second is 1.5.

Scaling by X or Y in pixels will retain the original aspect ratio. Getting the right size involves knowing the desired dpi.

```r
install.packages("magic")
library(magick)
```

```r
Image <- image_read("https://i.stack.imgur.com/42fvN.png")
print(Image)
```

[image]

```r
# Increase 300 in X dimension
Image_300x <- image_scale(Image, "300")
print(Image_300x)
```

[image]

```r
# Increase 300 in y
Image_300y <- image_scale(Image, "x300")
print(Image_300y)
```

[image]